# keyset pagination on extended query with full text search in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a database with 4 tables. These 4 tables hold users, their relations with each other (users following other users), the posts they make and the likes they receive. I have simplified the tables for better understanding.

```
// table: users
+-------------------------------------------------+
| user_id | username | timestamp_joined | tokens  |
+-------------------------------------------------+

// table: followers
+-------------------------------------------------+
| follower_id | user_id | following_user_id       |
+-------------------------------------------------+

// table: posts
+-------------------------------------------------+
| post_id | user_id | timestamp_posted            |
+-------------------------------------------------+

// table: post_likes
+-------------------------------------------------+
| post_like_id | post_id | user_id                |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I want to do a **full text search** combined with a **keyset pagination**. I've managed to create a query for the full text search, but I fail at modifying that query for keyset pagination.

### **What I want**

I want to search for users, but I don't want to rank them on user_id. I want to rank them on 3 things, listed below, in that order.

1) First, I want to rank them on `ts_rank(tokens, plainto_tsquery('search query'))`. The better there is a match between tokens (a column containing a to_tsvector object) and the search query, the higher the user should appear in the search results.

2) Secondly, I want to rank them on popularity. When 2 users have the same level of match on a search query, I want the most popular user to appear first. I have created a small equation to calculate the popularity. **I know it's not a good equation, but for now (and for testing), it works. I will think about a better equation when it all works.**

```
// equation parameters
d = # days user exists
f = # followers for a user
p = # posts made by a user in the last 5 days
l = total # likes on the posts made by the user in the last 5 days

// equation
(0.25 * d * (0.25 * f)) + (0.001 * d) + SQRT((f/d)) + ((0.1 * p) * (l/p))
```

3) When users still have the same level of match on a search query AND the same popularity, I want the oldest users to appear first (`ORDER BY user_id ASC`).

### **First attempt of creating a query (no keyset pagination yet)**

The query to do all this is very extended, and I'm not sure about the performance when the number of rows increase.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    username,
    ts_rank(tokens, plainto_tsquery('search query')) AS search_rank,
    (
        (0.25 * (SELECT EXTRACT('day' FROM date_trunc('day', NOW() - timestamp_joined::date))) * (0.25 * ((SELECT COUNT(follower_id) FROM followers WHERE following_user_id = user_id)))
        +
        (0.001 * (SELECT EXTRACT('day' FROM date_trunc('day', NOW() - timestamp_joined::date))))
        +
        (SQRT(((SELECT COUNT(follower_id) FROM followers WHERE following_user_id = user_id)/(SELECT EXTRACT('day' FROM date_trunc('day', NOW() - timestamp_joined::date)))))
        +
        ((0.1 * (SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM posts WHERE user_id = user_id AND timestamp_posted > NOW() - INTERVAL '5 DAY')) * ((SELECT COUNT(post_like_id) FROM post_likes WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE user_id = user_id))/(SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM posts WHERE user_id = user_id AND timestamp_posted > NOW() - INTERVAL '5 DAY')))
    ) AS popularity_rank
FROM
    users
ORDER BY
    search_rank DESC,
    popularity_rank DESC,
    user_id ASC
```

As you can see, this is a complicated query (especially with the equation), with **9** SELECT statements in it. But the query works.

### **My questions**

1) First of all, I want to know something about the **performance** of this query. I'm a beginner, and I really don't know how the PostgreSQL works in the back. 9 SELECT-statements in 1 query, to me, it seems a lot. Will the performance drop when the database hits, let's say, +1,000,000 records in each table? Will adding indexes to the tables help?

2) Secondly, I want to know how I can add a **keyset pagination** to this query.

I know it's a lot, but I wanted to make one question to get a better overview.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, some subqueries are unnnecessary. Instead of

```
(SELECT EXTRACT('day' FROM date_trunc('day', NOW() - timestamp_joined::date)))
```

you might as well write

```
EXTRACT('day' FROM date_trunc('day', NOW() - timestamp_joined::date)
```

Second, rather than having subselects in the `SELECT` list, you should `OUTER JOIN`  the table `users` with the other tables.

Finally, if you want the query to be fast, any you want to use keyset pagination, you'll have to create an index that supports the `ORDER BY`, that is and index that covers the complete `ORDER BY` clause. But since your `ORDER BY` clause depends on parameters (`searchquery`) and the content of other tables, that is not possible.

So efficient keyset pagination is not possible unless you use a different query. An alternative would be to use a `WITH HOLD` cursor that materializes the whole query result on the server and fetch it page by page.

Comment: You are right about the day extraction subquery, I didn't notice it. Thank you. I rethought the query and I'm not doing a keyset pagination anymore. The fact is that let's say 90% of the users will not scroll down the first 100 results, because the first 100 results are the best/most popular matches for their search query.